# wordpress permalinks redirect https

Tags: wordpress, redirect, https, permalinks

I am using WordPress permalinks for my site. And I am setting up .htaccess redirect for SSL. right now it only works for the home page. but not the others. I know it is a issue of I am using permalinks for all the other page

I was wondering is there anyway that I can simply set up SSL redirect for permalinks? I have tried .htaccess redirect to a specific page, and it is still not working.

Any help will be appreciates. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check your apache configuration and verify that for the directory in which you store your Wordpress installation you have following settings enabled (probably you will have more configuration options for the specific directory, but these are the minimum required for Wordpress fancy permalinks):

```
<Directory var/www/>
FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Thanks